# The tired exam proctor (probability, scheduling)

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

An exam is being written by students who are sitting in an $m \times n$ grid in a classroom.  The proctor, who is both extremely bored and extremely well acquainted with his students, has assigned each student a probability $P_{i,j}$ of asking a question during the exam.  The proctor also knows that once a student has asked a question, their probability of asking a question is reduced to $\alpha_{i,j}P_{i,j}$, where $\alpha_{i,j} < 1$.

Once a student asks a question, the proctor must travel from his current position to the student's location to answer the question.

Let us now assume that the proctor is "tired" - he wants to travel the least Manhattan Distance possible over the course of the exam.  Now, I suspect but cannot prove several things, and I'd like to know if my suspicions are correct (or at least valid) and how to go about investigating further:

I suspect that:

1) The optimal thing for the proctor to do, once he has answered a question, is to travel to the location that is nearest the highest average probability.  I envision something like a "probability center", similar to the center of mass, and this is where the proctor should move to.

2) Not moving to this center of probability is sub-optimal, since it is more likely students near this center of probability are going to ask questions right after the other.

Is there a more formal, possibly well-studied, version of this problem that I can start taking a look at?

Comment: Or just take sick leave?

Comment: 1) You'd have to compare whether moving to the center of probability is worth it or not 2) Consider a scenario where the probabilities are very high (say $1$, even -- every student has a question right off the bat). He's better off starting near the front and slowly working his way back, as opposed to walking to the middle first.

Comment: I agree on (1), but not necessarily on (2).  At the very beginning you may be right, but after the first question has been asked somewhere in the room the center of probability would shift dramatically, would it not?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Not necessarily -- depends on the probabilities and current position.You have to see if the movement is worth it by comparing what would happen on average if you had stayed put vs. moved to some other spot. It also depends somewhat on the problem parameters. Are questions asked at independent times across all students? How long does the test take? What's the proctor's rate of movement? How long does it take him to answer a question? etc etc etc.

Comment: interesting.  The only way I can think of to get that data would be to run it numerically a bunch of times.  I can't imagine that's the only way.  What would be an approach to setting it up symbolically?